# Cyclos4 - Apache as frontend for a Tomcat app

Tags: tomcat, apache-2.4, tomcat7

I just install Cyclos4 software into my server. I can access to the app via:

`http://IP:8080/cyclos`

Now I'm trying to access to the app without having to write the port and the `/cyclos`. I follow Cyclos's manual:

http://documentation.cyclos.org/4.5/cyclos-reference/ch01s03.html#d0e474

But I'm totally lose. I have uncomment the line that they say (I don't change any port) and create the following `.conf` for the VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/cyclos
 ServerName IP 
 #Because I don't have domain yet, I want first to be sure  that it works
 <IfModule mod_jk.c>
       JkMount /* ajp13_worker
       JkMount / ajp13_worker      
 </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

But didn't work. What I'm not doing well?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are using modjk. Better use mod_proxy. It is easier

Comment: Hi, finally I decided to redirect the traffic with a index.php with the function redirect. Much easier, I guess. But thank you raupach, I'll keep it in mind for the next time.

Comment: I really suggest you have a look at mod_proxy_http. It is just a couple of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mod_proxy_http. It is much easier to configure than mod_jk. It looks like all you need is a Apache frontend.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.example.com

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://<tomcat-ip-address>:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / <tomcat-ip-address>:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```